# Does Firefox 4 have keyboard shortcuts for the "Group your tabs" and "List all tabs" buttons?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-tabs

Firefox 4 has two features for visualizing tabs: the little button at the right end of the tab bar with the tooltip "List all tabs", and the "Group your tabs" button, which brings up the panorama thingy for putting tabs in groups. Does either of these have a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an article about keyboard shortcuts in Firefox Help: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard%20shortcuts#w_windows-tabs

It mentions that the shortcut for the Tab Groups View is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.